# How to detect failure of 3rd party cookies in Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, cookies, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a webapp that uses Firebase and FirebaseAuth. Users sign in with Google via the signInWithRedirect method. It works great in normal circumstances.

But, some of my users can't log in if their Chrome settings are set to block 3rd Party cookies, which is inconvenient but not unexpected.

How do I catch this behavior in my Javascript when this happens? Currently, when the cookie is blocked, the user is just returned to the previous screen, not signed in, but no error is shown. I want to catch the "error" and alert the user. If there a way to detect the browser's ability to save 3rd party cookies, or an error code in signInWithRedirect that will notice the blocked cookie?

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');  
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });

firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
  .then(() => firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider));
```

Comment: this issue tracks the problem https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3004